# SASS Syntax Highlighting in Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sass

Currently I use this plugin for syntax highlighting in Visual Studio http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench

Personally I don't like it at all. It has limited features and poor formatting compared to other editors. In my freelance work I use Sublime Text 2 and Aptana which have excellent support for SASS. But at my job I have to use Visual Studio. Does anyone else know of a good plugin that has SASS support?

I don't care if it builds the files I do that through the command line anyway. I just want something that has good syntax support.

Comment: It says, towards the bottom, that Web essentials has some added functionality when using web-workbench.  Have you installed Web Essentials? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f

Comment: @TNCodeMonkey I have not installed that. I also couldn't find that posted on the site. I will install that and see if it helps. Thanks

Comment: I hope that it will, somehow I now have LESS styling in my apps now.  If not, it is still a really great extension for Web Developers.

Comment: @TNCodeMonkey I didn't pay attention but currently this extension only supports 2010 and I'm running 2012.

Comment: are you talking about the Mindscape Workbench or Web Essentials?

Comment: @TNCodeMonkey Web Essentials, sorry

Comment: My bad, here is the correct link:  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6

Comment: @TNCodeMonkey thanks I installed that so we'll see how it goes. The syntax highlighting support didn't change it's still slow and doesn't work until I close braces and add ; but it added some other features that I do like

Comment: glad that you like it, and sorry that it didn't work.

Comment: did you try Sass for Visual Studio? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbb2ab3d-265e-4749-8b4c-8bd907227627 I just thinking about installing it myself, but not sure if it's good.

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately that doesn't provide a Syntax highlighter it only provides a different solution to compiling the code

Comment: I gave up of the web-workbench as well. I'm luck that I can use Sublime Text 2 at work so, in Visual Studio, I set "Sublime Text 2" as the default editor for *.sass, *.scss files. Not ideal, but does the job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try SassyStudio. It's free and works with VS 2012/13:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85fa99a6-e4c6-4a1c-9f00-e6a8129b6f4d?SRC=VSIDE

I also didn't want to pay $39 a year for Web Workbench. SassyStudio works perfectly for me.

Here are the settings I'm using ([given to me by the developer](https://github.com/darrenkopp/SassyStudio/issues/27)):

- Environment

  - Fonts and Colors
  - Scroll down
  - "Display items"
  - Click on an item, i.e. "SCSS CSS Property Name"
  - Change the "Item foreground" color (leave background alone)
- Sassy

  - Studio Experimental Intellisense: True
- Text Editor

  - File Extension
  - Ensure there are no css, scss or sass file extensions (delete any that exist)

Restart VS for these changes to take effect.

Comment: This looks very promising. Do you know if there's a way to customize the colors for the syntax highlighting? Right now the parent elements are just black and I would like to change that. I don't see anything in the documentation so I assume I have to change it in the VS settings

Comment: The problem is, SassyStudio doesn't work in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

In VS 2012 open menu Tools > Options, on left side select menu Text Editor > File Extension and then add scss as extension and choose CSS Source Editor from dropdown as editor

Comment: That doesn't work so well. When you begin nesting elements in the `.scss` syntax it breaks the indenting. Nice idea though

Comment: I like this idea. All I want is indentation. :D

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 adds sass syntax highlighting:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/02/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-2-rc.aspx

I'm just working out how to get compass going with it. :)

Comment: Oh snap, Microsoft is catching on!