# How to edit .SASS file (not .SCSS) with syntax highlighting (css style) on VISUAL STUDIO 2017?

Tags: sass, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2017

Anybody here knows how to edit .SASS (NOT .SCSS) with  highlighted syntax (cSS style) On visual studio 2017?

Or even setup up the visual studio to recognize .SASS files as CSS or SCSS?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SASS Syntax Highlighting in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646775/sass-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @jcolemang I doubt you even visited that link, the answer and question are old, and the link provided only works for [visual studio 2012/2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTT2J.png)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue as well. SASS highlighting is not working.